# Maven errors when install on an Eclipse project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I'm trying to install maven on four projects. Let me explain the context :

I have a project (not mine), and I'm trying to run it but I have errors in the code and it's obviously maven errors. I have configured the Maven Environnement with this tuto : http://www.tutorialspoint.com/maven/maven_environment_setup.htm and it seems to work.

About the project, the entire project is dividing in four projects. I own only this four project, maybe they don't give me all the sources of the project (stupid) but why not.

So I'm trying to install maven in each projects and I have some errors, could you tell me what it means please ? And what should I do to resolve it ?

[image]

Text version :

```
C:\Users\Lison\workspace\Persyst_1.4>mvn clean install -U
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading: 

https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/eu/akka/AkkaToulouseSuperPom/1
.0/AkkaToulouseSuperPom-1.0.pom
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for fr.inra.grignon:persyst:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Coul
d not find artifact eu.akka:AkkaToulouseSuperPom:pom:1.0 in central (https://rep
o.maven.apache.org/maven2) and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @
 line 6, column 10
 @
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR]   The project fr.inra.grignon:persyst:1.0-SNAPSHOT (C:\Users\Lison\works
pace\Persyst_1.4\pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM for fr.inra.grignon:persyst:1.0-SNAPSHOT:
Could not find artifact eu.akka:AkkaToulouseSuperPom:pom:1.0 in central (https:/
/repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local P
OM @ line 6, column 10 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
ch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildin
gException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/UnresolvableMo
delException
```

**EDIT : **

```
Project 1
    >src
    >compile
    >pom.xml
Project 2
    >src
    >pom.xml
Project 3
    >src
    >pom.xml
Project 4
    >src
    >pom.xml
```

Comment: It seems like you're trying to use an artifact that's not resolvable in the central repository. If that is some in-house developement artifact you may need to run mvn install for that artifact before retrying

Comment: Is this a multi-module Maven project? If so, you need to run Maven commands from the parent pom (root POM).

Comment: Could you please post messages as text and not as bitmaps?

Comment: @Tunaki The problem is that I have only this 4 project and no parent :/ Maybe I didn't understand, what is "root POM" ?

Comment: Do you need a proxy to access the internet?

Comment: Please post the directory structure of your project

Comment: @Tunaki I edited with the structure of the project

Comment: @Erlaunis don't you have parent?

Comment: @Soorapadman I don't think, and I guess that's the problem ...

Comment: it showing Non-resolvable parent POM it means this indicates that maven did search locally for the parent pom, but found that it was not the correct pom or missing. if the project is multimodule it should have parent project.

Comment: @Soorapadman Ok, thanks, that's what I wanted to know :)

Comment: you are welcome I will add this answer.accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is showing

> Non-resolvable parent POM for fr.inra.grignon:persyst:1.0-snapshot

it means this indicates that maven did search locally for the parent pom, but found that it was not the correct pom or missing. if the project is multimodule it should have parent project.

Reference For multimodule Project you may check this link:

https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html

Comment: Do you know if this parent project has something special ? I mean, is it possible that I create one or not ?

Comment: yes  you can create. that contain only pom.xml. under pom.xml you should have all modules should specify

Comment: I guess I have to link it to the other projects in Eclipse ? How should I do ?

Comment: @Erlaunis once you create a parent and add your project 1,2,3,4 in pom.xml  that's fine it will open all project

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92869/discussion-between-erlaunis-and-soorapadman).